# How to show the contents of this td only if it has overflow text of some other td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

The last `td` has its own content. I need the overflowed text text to be stopped before the `td` which has text.

Is there any way specify width like attributes for overflow text.

REQUIRED SCENARIO:

All `td`'s have `overflow: visible`. It should be visible only till a `td` has text.  It shouldn't apply on the `td` which has text. And if i remove the text in the normal `td`, the previously overflowed text should be shown fully. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any sample to play with?

Comment: So no sample to share??? I ask it because your senario is missing some cases so that's not clear what you are expecting. What should happen if a cell isn't empty between one overflowing and an empty one? What if it is the last cell of a row wich is overflowing? Etc... You could use e.g `$('#codexpl td ~ td:not(:empty)').prev('td:not(:empty)').css('overflow','hidden');` or `$('#codexpl td + td:not(:empty)').prevAll('td:not(:empty)').css('overflow','hidden');` depending expected case. But you seem to let user edit cell, so you need to call it from relevant handler (which is???).

Comment: My requirement https://jsfiddle.net/zvbLz2n3/ if a cell has text, no overflow text of any other cell should overlay on it.